# How to quickly parse the following data into a data structure

Tags: c#, .net

I have data like

A=B&C=D&E=F

How to quickly parse it into a data structure like a dictionary? Any built-in support from .net framework?

Comment: Pretty much depend on what the interpretation of the data should be. You could enhance the question by giving an example of what you want the end result to be

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    var input = "A=B&C=D&E=F";
    var output = input
                    .Split(new string[] {"&"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                    .Select(s => s.Split('=', 2))
                    .ToDictionary(d => d[0], d => d[1]);
```

Comment: I like this method, since it will work for separator characters other than '=' and '&'. Could decide to tomorrow to use '|' and '-' instead, and it would be a simple replacement in the code

Comment: You could even generalize it so you can reuse it.

Comment: I would use `s.Split(new [] { '=' }, 2)` to ensure that the pair is split in two even if the value part of the data contains more equals signs.

Answer (score 4):

Use the HttpUtility.ParseQueryString()-Method:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046.aspx

It will return a NameValueCollection, which is very similary to a dictionary.

Comment: under the assumption that & is a delimitor and K=V is a key value pair An assumption I believe is correct but not stated anywhere

Answer (score 2):

Yep, LINQ is your friend here.

```
string myString = "A=B&C=D&E=F";

var dictionary = myString.Split('&')
  .Select(pair => pair.Split('='))
  .ToDictionary (array => array[0], array => array[1]);
```